# PostgreSQL 9.3 not uninstalling Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9.3 and 9.4 installed, now I want to uninstall 9.3 to remove conflicts

I removed it using:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.3
```

But when I run `$ ps aux|grep postgres` I get this:

```
postgres  6858  0.0  0.4 254828 16796 ?        S    11:04   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
postgres  6860  0.0  0.0 254828  1896 ?        Ss   11:04   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
postgres  6861  0.0  0.0 254828  2688 ?        Ss   11:04   0:00 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
postgres  6862  0.0  0.0 254828  1680 ?        Ss   11:04   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
postgres  6863  0.0  0.0 255232  2716 ?        Ss   11:04   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
postgres  6864  0.0  0.0 109972  1808 ?        Ss   11:04   0:00 postgres: stats collector process                                                                                           
amitoj    9414  0.0  0.0  15940   936 pts/3    S+   11:13   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
postgres  9812  0.0  0.2 251956 11060 ?        S    Jan14   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
postgres  9815  0.0  0.1 252092  6652 ?        Ss   Jan14   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
postgres  9816  0.0  0.0 251956  2452 ?        Ss   Jan14   0:00 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
postgres  9817  0.0  0.0 251956  3876 ?        Ss   Jan14   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
postgres  9818  0.0  0.0 252760  2952 ?        Ss   Jan14   0:02 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
postgres  9819  0.0  0.0 107912  1920 ?        Ss   Jan14   0:01 postgres: stats collector process                                                                                           
postgres 32059  0.0  0.4 254828 16360 ?        S    10:02   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
postgres 32061  0.0  0.0 254828  1832 ?        Ss   10:02   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
postgres 32062  0.0  0.0 254828  2632 ?        Ss   10:02   0:00 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
postgres 32063  0.0  0.0 254828  1616 ?        Ss   10:02   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
postgres 32064  0.0  0.0 255232  2540 ?        Ss   10:02   0:02 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
postgres 32065  0.0  0.0 109972  1756 ?        Ss   10:02   0:00 postgres: stats collector process
```

Visibly, 9.3 is still there. What should I do?

I am using Django 1.9 which requires PostgreSQL 9.4+ and I encounter an error due to the presence of 9.3 version.

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you shut down the server first?

Comment: I restarted the server using `$ sudo server postgresql restart`

Comment: So that is a "no" to @jos his question. I would advice to shutdown a database before attempting to delete it from your system ;)

Comment: But when I did restart it, only 9.4 was shown. So I assumed it was shut down. Should I still have shut down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is shutdown the server first by typing:

> sudo pg_ctlcluster

Check [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html)

then list all PostgreSQL packages by typing:

> dpkg -l | grep postgres

and finally remove the packages that I want for example:

> sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-9.3

Comment: I followed this and removed the packages but I still get the same output when I run `ps aux|grep postgres`.

Comment: The command you are running lists all postgres processes so what you should do is kill all running processes using the command `sudo pkill -u postgres` or `pkill postgres`.